# Integrating LDAvis with shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to take advantage of the shiny integration that came with LDAvis version 0.3.1. The example given on github (https://github.com/cpsievert/LDAvis/tree/master/inst/examples/shiny) is:

```
library(LDAvis)
library(shiny)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  output$myChart <- renderVis({
    with(TwentyNewsgroups,
         createJSON(phi, theta, doc.length, vocab, term.frequency,
                    R = input$nTerms))})
})

ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    sliderInput("nTerms", "Number of terms to display", min = 20, max = 40, value = 30),
    visOutput('myChart')
  )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

This app doesn't render any outputs, though, so I'm a bit confused. Can anyone help with a minimal example of how to integrate LDAvis into a shiny app?

Comment: I tried this. When you replace `visOutput` with `textOutput` and `renderVis`with `renderText`, it works as expected. Otherwise, the server method does not even react to input changes. My guess is that it has to do with the LDAvis package itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This piece of code worked on my machine, still the javascript takes some time to laod (about 20 seconds). Does this help you?

```
library(shiny)
library(LDAvis)

data(TwentyNewsgroups, package = "LDAvis")
ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    sliderInput("nTerms", "Number of terms to display", min = 20, max = 40, value = 30),
    visOutput('myChart')
  )
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  output$myChart <- renderVis({
    if(!is.null(input$nTerms)){
      with(TwentyNewsgroups, 
           createJSON(phi, theta, doc.length, vocab, term.frequency, 
                      R = input$nTerms))


    } 
           })
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: It does react, but since the plugin seems very "heavy", this takes way too long. Alternative would be to include an action button (i.e. isolate the input).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.