# Predict values from lda results

Tags: r, shiny

I have a dataframe like this:

```
   name keyword1  keyword2  keyword3 
  artA      0          1        0 
  artA      1          1        0  
  artB      0          0        1
  artB      1          1        0  
  artC      1          1        0
```

and I use lda

```
library(lda)
m <- MASS::lda(df$name~.,data=df)
```

after that step how can I visualize the results and see the predictor?

I try to visualize the results form m using the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39248209):

```
library(shiny)
library(LDAvis)

ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    sliderInput("nTerms", "Number of terms to display", min = 20, max = 40, value = 30),
    visOutput('myChart')
  )
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  output$myChart <- renderVis({
    if(!is.null(input$nTerms)){
      with(m, 
           createJSON(prior, counts, means, scaling, lev,svd, N, call, terms, xlevels, 
                      R = input$nTerms))


    } 
           })
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

but I receive this error when I open the app:

```
Error: argument is of length zero
```

any idea what can I do? In createJSON I have used all variables from str(m)

Comment: you posted the vis code in the context of shiny. I would recommend you first get the code working outside of shiny, and then integrate it into shiny. The error you see is probably related to a shiny issue, and not to making the plot. The shiny aspect makes things more complicated than necessary.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra I updated my code because I show in createJSON had the variable from str(TwentyNewsgroups) so I add the variable from str(m). But now I receive another error. Any hind even out of shiny for this graph will be very helpful for me.

Comment: Note that  `MASS::lda` refers to linear discriminant analysis vs. `LDAvis` which pertains Latent Dirichlet Allocation from topic modelling visualization.  As @PaulHiemstra suggested, iron out all data/modelling issues first only then move on visualization.

Comment: See here https://tgmstat.wordpress.com/2014/01/15/computing-and-visualizing-lda-in-r/ for an example of LDA viz. using ggplot2.